# How to print contents in vector

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I want to print some values in 'vector'.

```
vector<GLubyte> m_coneIndices;
m_coneIndices.resize(m_bodyIndexCount + m_diskIndexCount);
vector<GLubyte>::iterator index = m_coneIndices.begin();

// Body triangles
for (int i = 0; i < coneSlices * 2; i += 2) {
    *index++ = i;
    *index++ = (i + 1) % (2 * coneSlices);
    *index++ = (i + 3) % (2 * coneSlices);
}


// Disk triangles
for (int i = 1; i < coneSlices * 2 + 1; i += 2) {
    *index++ = diskCenterIndex;
    *index++ = i;
    *index++ = (i + 2) % (2 * coneSlices);
}
```

This is how the values stored in 'vector'. I tried like

```
cout << "indices"<< "\n";

for (int i=0; i<(coneSlices * 2 ); i+=2) {

    cout << m_coneIndices[i] << ' ' << m_coneIndices[i+1] << ' ' << m_coneIndices[i+2] << ' ' << "\n";
}
```

and that printed some garbage values. Let me know what is wrong with this code.

Comment: are you sure those sizes are proper? In your loops I see "i+=2", but you update three values in the vector... so it should be "i+=3" I think. You can use vector like an array, use "coneIndices[i] = ..." for instance.

Comment: You are doing terrible things to your `vector`. *Stahp!*

Comment: I found this code from http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596804831/ in section TouchCone

Answer (score 0):

use `push_back` to add to the vector

```
vector<GLubyte> m_coneIndices;

// Body triangles
for (int i = 0; i < coneSlices * 3; i += 3) {
    m_coneIndices.push_back(i);
    m_coneIndices.push_back((i + 1) % (2 * coneSlices));
    m_coneIndices.push_back((i + 3) % (2 * coneSlices));
}

// Disk triangles
for (int i = 1; i < coneSlices * 2 + 1; i += 2) {
    m_coneIndices.push_back(diskCenterIndex);
    m_coneIndices.push_back(i);
    m_coneIndices.push_back((i + 2) % (2 * coneSlices));
}
```

print:

```
cout << "indices"<< "\n";

for (size_t i = 0; i< m_coneIndices.size(); i+=3) {
    cout << m_coneIndices[i*3] << ' ' << m_coneIndices[i*3+1] << ' ' <<
            m_coneIndices[i*3+2] << ' ' << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing right. I changed code by

```
for (int i=0; i<(coneSlices * 2 ); i+=2) {

     printf("%d ",(int)m_coneIndices[i]);
}
```

and that worked.